# React-Native ScrollView makes TextInput vanish

Tags: ios, scrollview, react-native, textinput

Being pretty new to React Native, hopefully this is an obvious oversight, but I've experimented and not found a solution. It's a pretty straightforward problem: when I have a couple of Views and a TextInput, everything lays out as expected. When I wrap them in a ScrollView, the Views remain but the TextInput no longer renders. I have not been able to figure out why.

To test and share it I created an rnplay app here: https://rnplay.org/apps/P774EQ

As you can see, the text in the Views wrapping the TextInput appear as expected, but the TextInput isn't there. If you just remove the ScrollView (lines 18 & 39), the TextInput appears.

Hopefully someone experienced will look at this and have an answer in a few seconds because I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Line17: `style={styles.scrollview}` => `style={styles.scrollView}`, you have a spell mistake.

2) Use `contentContainerStyle` for ScrollView ([for more details about contentContainerStyle](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#props))

```
<ScrollView keyboardDismissMode='interactive' style={styles.scrollview} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}>
```

and here is the contentContainerStyle:

```
contentContainerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
}
```

3) The `flex` property of `message` style is better to set as `.125` because the `flex` of `inputcontainer` is `.75`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried the contentContainerStyle before without success but I don't know why -- that did fix it. I still find it mysterious that without it the Text elements still displayed but the TextInput didn't, and I'm not sure why that is, but this did fix the problem. I have updated the rnplay application in case it may help others in the future.